# Gecko Engine in ABCPDF not rendering text color

Tags: gecko, abcpdf

I'm using ABCPDF + Gecko to render some PDFs within an HTML->PDF templating engine I'm writing. I switched to Gecko specifically to be able to render embedded SVG graphics for things like signatures. However, it seems that now all font colors have changed to black,regardless of the style sheet, class names, or even inline styles being used. Is this a gecko configuration problem, a problem with ABCPDF, or ... ??

Example HTML:

```
<span style="color:blue;">This should be blue</span>
```

I'm specifying no options besides browser size, and didn't customize anything in the `XULRunner21_0` folder. I'm using `AddImageHtml` to add the html to a PDF document.

**Update:** after some more research looks like this may be tied to how Gecko treats text upon printing (not the same as media type). Is there a setting that will prevent it from mucking with the visuals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being caused by including bootstrap css in my little project. Removing the print media bits from my copy of bootstrap resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for logging this, it was driving me absolutely crazy. I had exactly the same problem and solution.